# JQuery plugin Slick & Flexbox: two slides show on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I'm trying to show a carousel of slides within a flexbox container. There are two problems:

1. On the initial load two slides are shown instead of just one. This is corrected when scrolling through the slides. There is a blue border around the slide container.
2. If I set the slick property `outline: none` to get rid of the blue border all the slides show in a column. Shown in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u85bt7vf/). (Don't know how to demonstrate part 1 of this problem because it loads an other HTML file).

Here is my code:
HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="middleContainer">
    <div id= "questionContainer">
    <!-- contains question and set of buttons -->
      <div class = "questions" id = "questionText">
      <!-- load questions here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-color: #DEA940;
}

#middleContainer {
    width: 40%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #DEA940;/*#F3D04D;*/
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: space-around;
    flex-grow: <property unused>
    flex-shrink: <property unused>
    flex-basis: <property unused>
}

#questionContainer {
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction:column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 2%;
    background-color: #FFF764;
    border: 1% solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #fff764;
}
```

JS

```
$("#questionText").load("questions.html", function () {
    $('.questions').slick({
        outline: none,
        slidesToShow: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: OK. Not used JSFiddle before but I'll give it a go

Comment: JSFiddle added to demonstrate second part of the problem

Comment: Slick plugin does not have outline property. For first problem try to add overflow hidden to the `.questions`. check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/u85bt7vf/4//)

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood this outline [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468430/slick-js-remove-blue-highlight-around-image) for the blue box - it applies to slick-slide

Comment: Alireza - please could you try posting your link again. It isn't working.

Comment: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/u85bt7vf/4/)